# symfony/thanks contains a Composer plugin which is blocked by your allow-plugins config

Tags: php, symfony, gitlab, composer-php

I work with Symfony 5.4, docker env and GitLab.
When I run my pipeline at the command, `composer install` I have the following error:

```
In PluginManager.php line 762:
                                                                               
  symfony/thanks contains a Composer plugin which is blocked by your allow-pl  
  ugins config. You may add it to the list if you consider it safe.            
  You can run "composer config --no-plugins allow-plugins.symfony/thanks [tru  
  e|false]" to enable it (true) or disable it explicitly and suppress this ex  
  ception (false)                                                              
  See https://getcomposer.org/allow-plugins
```

I try

```
composer global config allow-plugins.composer/installers true
composer clearcache
composer self-update
composer update --no-plugins --noscripts
```

But nothing works and I got the same error ...

Comment: Did you run: `composer config --no-plugins allow-plugins.symfony/thanks true` ?

Comment: Yes but I still have the same error

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try to add this config to your composer.json.

```json
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "symfony/thanks": true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I tried that too, but it still doesn't work

Comment: When I tried your solution I had the same error but with symfony/flex so I added this to my composer.json

```
 "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/thanks": true
        },
```

Now everything is working fine again

Answer (score 0):

don't know if it's the best solution or not, but you can go to your composer global dir and do remove it at all :)

```
cd ~/.config/composer
composer remove symfony/thanks
```